# Forwarding a function pointer

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

I was surprised to find out that apparently `std::forward` cannot be used with arbitrary types, although the documentation suggests that.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
void bar(T&&);

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& v) {
    bar(std::forward(v));
}

int main() {
    foo(main);
}
```

produces

```
forward.cc: In instantiation of 'void foo(T&&) [with T = int (&)()]':
forward.cc:12:13:   required from here
forward.cc:8:23: error: no matching function for call to 'forward(int (&)())'
     bar(std::forward(v));
                       ^
forward.cc:8:23: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/utility:70,
                 from forward.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:76:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr _Tp&& std::forward(typename std::remove_reference<_From>::type&)
     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:76:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
forward.cc:8:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Tp'
     bar(std::forward(v));
                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/utility:70,
                 from forward.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:87:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr _Tp&& std::forward(typename std::remove_reference<_From>::type&&)
     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/move.h:87:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
forward.cc:8:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Tp'
     bar(std::forward(v));
```

Maybe I'm mislead by the new universal reference syntax or my GCC is having a bad day.

I'm using GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: Well, that was quick. And also pretty stupid of me. Make an answer from that and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::forward<T>()` takes a parameter whose type cannot be deduced. You have to supply the template argument manually:

> ```
> std::forward<T>(v);
> //          ^^^
> ```